# How do I add new nodes to the end of a pre existing node list?

Tags: c, data-structures, nodes

so I have this creating the list at first

```
void add(struct node **head,char FirstN[],char LastN[],float score,char zipcode[])
{
    struct node *new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(new_node->FirstN,FirstN);
    strcpy(new_node->LastN,LastN);
    strcpy(new_node->zipcode,zipcode);
    new_node->score=score;
    new_node->next=(*head);
    (*head)=new_node;
}
```

I need a different function to add multiple nodes to the end of this pre-existing list.

How can I do that? 
Any guidance much appreciated!

Comment: You need to walk the list and point the last node->next to your new node/list.

Comment: So basically, you need a `getLastNode()` or you need to always update a `listTail` variable.  Often a list will consist of both head and tail nodes.

Comment: Or simply declare a `tail` pointer that always points to the last node and then you can insert at end in O(1) time with `tail->next = new_node; tail = new_node;`. Otherwise iterating will be O(n) time and insertions decrease in efficiency with each added node. What you are doing now is called *forward chaining* which results in your list being in reverse order of the inputs.

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take an extra pointer variable of type node * , it will always point to the last element of your node list. Whenever you want to append any new node to your list ,you don't need to traverse through the list from the head(start node) of your list. just change the value of that pointer which is pointing to the last node.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me how to get the last node of a linked list?